# Python - Django - Pass serializer and attribute as argument

Tags: python, django, generics, attributes, serialization

currently i am dealing with this snippet:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super().to_representation(instance)

    representation['categories'] = CategorySerializer(instance.categories, many=True).data

    return representation
```

Now i would like to make the snippet

```
representation['categories'] = CategorySerializer(instance.categories, many=True).data
```

more generic, so i can pass any field and its corresponding serializer here, like:

```
representation[config['field']] = config['serializer'](instance[getattr(instance, config['field'])]).data
```

but it crashed totally, anybody ever dealed with this kind of generic setup?

thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0):

do you want to be doing:

```
instance[getattr(instance, config['field'])]
```

this seems to be too many levels of indirection, maybe you want to just do:

```
getattr(instance, config['field'])
```

instead.  I'd also be tempted to save your config members locally for readability:

```
field = config['field']
serializer = config['serializer']
representation[field] = serializer(getattr(instance, field)).data
```

which looks more readable

Comment: mhm yea but i can not call: instance.getattr(instance, config['field']) ... i need to somehow call the property on the instance object from the string i get from the config...

Comment: can you or anybody refer to it?

Comment: what do you mean "call the property"?  do you mean it's a method, if so you can just put method invocation brackets at after the `getattr` as normal in python…  e.g. `getattr(a,'b')()` is the same as `a.b()`